# Comparing one column value to all columns in linux enviroment

Tags: python, awk, sed, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

So I have two files , one VCF that looks like

```
88  Chr1    25  C   -   3   2   1   1
88  Chr1    88  A   T   7   2   1   1
88  Chr1    92  A   C   16  4   1   1
```

and another with genes that looks like

```
GENEID  Start END
GENE_ID 11 155
GENE_ID 165 999
```

I want a script that looks if there is a gene position (3rd column of VCF file) within the range of second and third position of the second file and then to print it out.

What I did so far was to join the files and do

```
awk '{if (3>$12 && $3< $13) print }' > out
```

What I did only compares current rows of joined files (it only prints if the value is in the same row),  how can I make it compare all rows of column 3 to all rows of column 12 and 13?

Best,
Serg

Comment: You want to print *what* out when that happens? You want to compare every line from the VCF file to every line in the gene id file? There's no need to join the files for this (and as you've seen that doesn't help you cross match and actively makes that harder in fact).

Comment: How large are thes files? How many rows do they have? Ten, a million?

Comment: there is one gene file and hudreds of VCF files.
gene one has around 1000 lines while VCFs have more... ranging from 5000-20000

Comment: You will beed to store the gene coordinates in memory, then loop thru the VCF and check the position of each variant against the coordinates of each gene. This is probably going to be tricky with awk, but straightforward with python. Of course it's going to be inefficient since you'll have to do 2000 comparisons for each VCF line. Can't you use something like BEDtools to do this?

Comment: @heathobrien I have just started working with the data, I havent used BEDtools before.
I am looking it up now to see if its useful for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope to help (**EDIT** i change the code for more efficient algorithm)

```
gawk '
  #read input.genes and create list of limits (min, max)
  NR == FNR {
    #without header in input
    if(NR>1) {
      for(i=$2; i<=$3; i++){
        limits[i]=limits[i]","$2"-"$3;
      }
    };
    next
  }
  #read input.vcf, if column 3 is range of limits then print
  {
    if($3 in limits){
      print $0, "between("limits[$3]")"
    }
  }' input.genes input.vcf
```

you get:

```
88  Chr1    25  C   -   3   2   1   1 between(,11-155)
88  Chr1    88  A   T   7   2   1   1 between(,11-155)
88  Chr1    92  A   C   16  4   1   1 between(,11-155)
```

This algorithm in python is optimized for very large file using dictionaries

```
limits = [line.strip().split() for line in open("input.genes")]
limits.pop(0) #remove the header
limits = [map(int,v[1:]) for v in limits]

dict_limits = {}
for start, finish in limits:
  for i in xrange(start, finish+1):
    if i not in dict_limits:
      dict_limits[i] = []
    dict_limits[i].append((start,finish))

OUTPUT = open("my_output.txt", "w")
for reg in open("input.vcf"):
  v_reg = reg.strip().split()
  if int(v_reg[2]) in dict_limits:
    OUTPUT.write(reg.strip() + "\tbetween({})\n".format(str(dict_limits[int(v_reg[2])])))

OUTPUT.close()
```

you get:

```
88  Chr1    25  C   -   3   2   1   1   between([(11, 155)])
88  Chr1    88  A   T   7   2   1   1   between([(11, 155)])
88  Chr1    92  A   C   16  4   1   1   between([(11, 155)])
```

Comment: I tried it and got no output at all :/
tried redirecting to a file and it came out empty.
could you explain me why you have the [NR -1,1] = $2 in the fifth line? what is -1,1 doing?

Comment: @srx because, your `input.genes` file has header, i must to remove it

Comment: there was a problem with handling for(i=1; i<=length(a); i++) , so I replaced it with for(i=1;i in a;i++)  -  different compiler I Guess , but the code doesn't give anything :/

Comment: @srx yes `for (i = 1; i in a ;i++ )` doesn't works, .....because `i in a` return `false`

Comment: If I leave it with the original command it says line 

11: illegal reference to array a.

Seems I was lacking GNU awk (GAWK) on this machine
It works! Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: Now it ran into a second problem , it uses up all the memory when it hits large files (I have some 500MB ones) and it justs says "Killed" and dies :(

I think Ill try with BEDtools , thank you for help anyway ^_^

Comment: @srx i use python for gff or vcf format analysis in large files .... but, It takes several minutes, even hours to file 100G

Comment: I have found a problem here , whenever it finds a number in VCF that doesnt fit the range it crashes. Shouldnt break handle that?

Comment: @srx it' isn't neccesary, using dictionary the complexity of algorithm is lineal ( O(n) ), then if the file has 100.000 lines, takes the same 100.000 iterations, even works better than the awk script , delivering all ranges to which it belongs

Comment: Its great!
And if I add a wildcard to input.vcf , it could run more than one vcf file?
Ill try to do that in shell with for file in ... do python

Comment: @srx of course, in python to use `sys.argv` in script

Comment: I'd just save the start and end of the range as numbers from the first file and then do a math > and < comparison when reading the 2nd file. Also stick a next at the end of the first block and remove the `NR != FNR` test from the second so you're not doing more tests than necessary and duplicating/negating conditions.